# Why do I get a warning every time I use malloc?

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, warnings, sizeof

If I use `malloc` in my code:

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

I get this warning from `gcc`:

```
new.c:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’  
new.c:7: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
```

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You need to add:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

This file includes the declaration for the built-in function `malloc`. If you don't do that, the compiler thinks you want to define your own function named `malloc` and it warns you because:

1. You don't explicitly declare it *and*
2. There already is a built-in function by that name which has a different signature than the one that was implicitly declared (when a function is declared implicitly, its return and argument types are assumed to be `int`, which isn't compatible with the built-in `malloc`, which takes a `size_t` and returns a `void*`).

Comment: Terminology nit: There's no such thing as a built-in function in C. malloc is simply a function from the Standard C Library.

Comment: @Jens I don't see a problem with referring to standard library functions as built-ins - and neither do the gcc people apparently since the error message used the word "built-in", too (which is why I did).

Comment: @sepp2k Well, I *do* see a problem. The usage is non-standard. *Compilers* can have built-in functions, and gcc may have malloc built-in. But as I wrote, *in C*, there are no built-in functions.

Answer (score 30):

You haven't done `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 16):

You need to include the header file that declares the function, for example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

If you don't include this header file, the function is not known to the compiler. So it sees it as undeclared.

Answer (score 10):

Make a habit of looking  your functions up in help.

Most help for C is modelled on the unix manual pages.

Using :

```
man malloc
```

gives pretty useful results.

Googling `man malloc` will show you what I mean.

In unix you also get apropos for things that are related.

Comment: Only if you already know that the line `#include <stdlib.h>` in the synopsis means you have to write that in your program.

Comment: If someone has read the other answers here then they will now know that.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the other very good answers, I would like to do a little nitpick and cover something what is not discussed yet in the other answers.

---

When you are at Linux, To use `malloc()` in your code,

You don´t actually **have  to** `#include <stdlib.h>`.

(Although the use of `stdlib.h` is very common and probably every non-toy-program should include it either way because it provides a wide range of useful C standard library functions and macros)

You could also `#include <malloc.h>` instead.

But please note that the use of `malloc.h` is deprecated and it makes your code non-portable. If you want to use `malloc()` you should always and ever (except for explicit reasons to do otherwise) `#include <stdlib.h>`.

The reasons *why*, are best explained in the answers to this question:

[difference between <stdlib.h> and <malloc.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973311/difference-between-stdlib-h-and-malloc-h)