# "Implicit declaration" warning

Tags: c, include, header, segmentation-fault

For this code:

```
int i=0; char **mainp;
for(i=0;i<2;++i)
{
    mainp[i]=malloc(sizeof(char)*200);
    if(!scanf("%[^#],#",mainp[i]))
        break;
   if(i<2)
       scanf("%[^#],#",mainp[i]);
}
```

GCC emits the warnings:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘scanf’
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘scanf’
warning: ‘mainp’ may be used uninitialized in this function
```

And I get a segmentation fault at runtime

input:(P>Q),(Q>R),-R#-P
  output:
     (P>Q),(Q>R),-R
           (empt slot)

i expected to give me 
       (P>Q),(Q>R),-R
       -P                   //where should i fix in my code such that it gives me expected 
                             //output

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get a warning everytime I use malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230386/why-do-i-get-a-warning-everytime-i-use-malloc)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Problem #1:**

> warning: ‘mainp’ may be used uninitialized in this function

You need to allocate memory for the array of arrays first.

```
char **mainp = malloc(sizeof(char*)*2);
```

**Problem #2:**

> warning: implicit declaration of function ‘scanf’
>    warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘scanf’

You need to include `stdio.h` at the top of your file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

**Problem #3: (Not included in your compiling warnings)**

Remember to free both the allocated array members and also the array of array address.

Answer (score 1):

gcc expects this line at the beginning of your file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

and a declaration of mainp like this one:

```
char *mainp[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use functions without declaring them; you used `scanf`, but at no point in your code is `scanf` declared. Since it's a standard library function it's declared in one of the standard headers, `stdio.h`, so you just need to include it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Brian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866520/implicit-declaration-of/2866529#2866529) is good for the other part