# get substring in c

Tags: c

I already have a function to get substring of a string

```
void subString(char* buffer, char* str, int start, int length)
{
    int i, x = 0;
    int end=start+length;
    for(i = start ; i <= end; i++)
        buffer[x++] = str[i];
    buffer[x] = '\0';

    //return temp;
}
```

new string is stored in buffer

but I prefer the function likes

```
char * subString(char* str, int start, int length)
{

    //.......

}
```

it will automatically returns the string pointer that has been alloced memory.

Welcome any comment

Comment: your `i <= (start+length)` is sospicious (wrong) e.g. "HELLO" with start=0 and length=2 should pick HE but i goes from 0 to 2 included, that is, it takes "HEL"

Comment: I thought the question was about the pros and cons of both function prototypes, but answers below are providing an implementation for the second one instead. It really is unclear what is asked. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with just adding the malloc into your new function and leaving the rest the same?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
char * subString(char* str, int start, int length) {
    char *newString = (char *)malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    int i, x = 0;
    int end=start+length;
    for(i = start ; i <= end; i++)
        newString[x++] = str[i];
    newString[x] = '\0';
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but don't cast the return value of `malloc` and don't take the size of `char` :-)

Comment: Why not? Being explicit doesn't reduce the clarity of the statement and it reinforces correct usage of `malloc`.

Comment: @cnicutar -- I see the topic has been closed, but I don't follow why I wouldn't cast `malloc` or use `sizeof(char)`?  Without casting in `gcc`, you get a warning (incompatible implicit definition of malloc) and without the sizeof, you may get a different size of char depending on architecture (although I agree that sizeof(char) is almost always 1).

Comment: @Chris Gregg This isn't C++. It's C :-) http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html and http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html . In C `sizeof(char) == 1` **always** (standard says so).

Comment: @Alex Reynolds See the link I posted

Comment: @cnicutar -- fine, but you still need the cast in `gcc`.

Comment: @Chris Gregg No, you don't :)

Comment: @cnicutar -- well then I guess you just like warnings. :)

Comment: @Chris Gregg `gcc` shouldn't warn you when not casting malloc. Are you sure you're not using C++ ?

Comment: `$ gcc substr.c 
    substr.c: In function ‘subString’:
    substr.c:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’`

Comment: @Chris Gregg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230386/why-do-i-get-a-warning-everytime-i-use-malloc :-))

Comment: @cnicutar -- my mistake!  I took out the `#include<stdlib>` to make sure it was needed; thanks for setting me straight! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are treating strings as simple character arrays, why don't you simply use plain old `strncpy`?

```
strncpy(dest, str+offset, len);
```