# Incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I'm getting this error:

> warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’

I am trying to do this:

```
fileinfo_list* tempList = malloc(sizeof(fileinfo_list));
```

Just for the reference the struct used at hand is:

```
typedef struct {
    fileinfo** filedata;
    size_t nFiles;
    size_t size;
    size_t fileblock;
} fileinfo_list;
```

I don't see anything wrong with what I've done. I'm just creating a `tempList` with the size of 1 x `fileinfo_list`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get a warning everytime I use malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230386/why-do-i-get-a-warning-everytime-i-use-malloc)

Answer (score 403, accepted):

You likely forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: ahh thanks :)
still getting the hang of C, first C program coming from java :)

Comment: after including `<stdlib.h>` the warning was replaced by an error `error: conflicting types for 'malloc'`

Answer (score 48):

You need to `#include <stdlib.h>`. Otherwise it's defined as `int malloc()` which is incompatible with the built-in type `void *malloc(size_t)`.

Comment: when it is defined as `int malloc()`, does it replicate `void *malloc(size_t)`?

Comment: @user1343318 Not necessarily, which is precisely the reason for the warning. Ex: a x64 platform with 64-bit data pointers and 32-bit `int` values will puke goat feces, while a x86 32bit-data-pointer/32bit-`int` can seemingly work correctly. *Neither* are correct, as in neither case is the compiler aware of what `malloc` actually returns, and assumes `int` in response.

Answer (score 16):

You're missing `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 5):

The stdlib.h file contains the header information or prototype of the malloc, calloc, realloc and free functions.

So to avoid this warning in ANSI C, you should include the stdlib header file.

Answer (score -4):

The only solution for such warnings is to include stdlib.h in the program.