# Array initialization in C causes Access Violation

Tags: c

Could someone please put me out of my misery and tell me why I get an Access Violation when initializing the array with ones?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void initData(float **data, size_t N)
{
    int i;
    *data = (float*)malloc( N * sizeof(float) );

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        *data[i] = 1.0;
    }
}

void main()
{
    float *data;
    initData(&data,8);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dereference (`*`) has a lower precedence than the square bracket operator `[]`.
What you write is thus effectively translated to:

```
*(data[i]) = 1.0;
```

whose failure shouldn't surprise anyone.

Change it to:

```
(*data)[i] = 1.0;
```

and it won't break.

---

[Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050798/incompatible-implicit-declaration-of-built-in-function-malloc) stdlib.h to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Ah yes makes sense when you thibnk of it like that. I didn't know about the precedence! Thanks