# difference between <stdlib.h> and <malloc.h>

Tags: c, gcc, malloc

When I use `malloc` in a C program, I get a warning:

```
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]
```

I can then include `<malloc.h>` or `<stdlib.h>` to get rid of the `warning` although it works without it as well.

**So I was wondering, what's the difference between these headers and which one does `gcc` links when I don't include anything?**

(I'm using `ubuntu 12.04 64-bit` with `gcc 4.6.3`)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `<malloc.h>` header is deprecated (and quite Linux specific, on which it defines *non-standard* functions like [mallinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html)). Use `<stdlib.h>` instead if you simply need [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) and related standard functions (e.g. `free`, `calloc`, `realloc` ....). Notice that `<stdlib.h>` is defined by [C89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C89) (and later) standards, but not `<malloc.h>`

Look into `/usr/include/malloc.h` you'll find there some non-standard functions (e.g. [malloc_stats(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_stats.3.html), etc...) - in addition of `malloc`....

And `gcc` don't link header files, but libraries. Read Levine's book about [linkers & loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) for more.

If you don't include any headers (and dont explicitly declare `malloc` yourself, which would be a bad idea), `malloc` is implicitly declared as returning some `int` value (which is wrong). I do invite you to pass at least the `-Wall` flag to `gcc` when using it.

You might also pass `-v` to `gcc` to understand the actual programs involved: `cc1` is the compiler proper (producing assembly code), `as` the assembler, `ld` the linker, and [collect2](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html) an internal utility which invokes the linker.

Comment: ye I guess linking was the wrong term. I meant to ask how does `gcc` find `malloc` function when I don't include any headers?

Comment: Linking is the good term. But the linker don't know the signature of C functions, only their names. Only the compiler proper (`cc1` started by `gcc`) care about the type signature of functions.

Comment: *"The <malloc.h> header is deprecated..."* - I just had to include it on a Debian 8.2 system with GCC 4.9. Apparently, its alive and kicking....

Comment: `<malloc.h>` can be both alive (existing header) and deprecated (recommended to not be used)

Comment: Surprisingly, memalign() is one of the non-standard functions declared in malloc.h.  It's not part of the C standard library

Comment: @JoelCunningham: That's [because the only standardized names are `posix_memalign` (POSIX) and `aligned_alloc`  (C11)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_memalign). `memalign` itself is "obsolete and non-standard".

Answer (score 15):

**stdlib.h** is a standard C header that declares among other things the `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `free()` functions. This is the header you should include.

**malloc.h** is a non-standard header, found on many systems where it often defines additional functions specific to the malloc implementation used by that platform.

If you do not include any of these, there's no default, however if you call `malloc()` without a prior declaration of the malloc function, C will assume the function prototype is `int malloc();`, which is often wrong. In addition to the headers, C compilers typically link to a standard library, e.g. glibc on Linux, where the implementation of malloc resides.

Note that there's a difference between header files and libraries. Header files declare things, like structs and function prototypes. Libraries contain the implementation, the compiled code. You link to library, and you `#include` header files.

Answer (score 7):

The headers declare different sets of functions, but both forward-declare `malloc`.

If you don't include either of them then you don't have a prototype for `malloc`, hence the warning. But you link against the same function regardless, because there is only one `malloc` function. It's just forward-declared in two places. The forward-declarations aren't there to help link against the `malloc` function, they're there so that the compiler can emit the correct code around the call, to specify the arguments and read the return value.

Note that `<malloc.h>` is not a standard include. I don't think `stdlib.h` ever includes `malloc.h` on GCC, but you can imagine that it might since that's one way to provide the necessary declaration.

Comment: just to make it clear, it doesn't give me an `error` but a `warning`. program works fine without me including anything.

Comment: @gokcehan: you should heed the warning, though. There's an actual bug that can occur as a result of calling `malloc` without a prototype in scope, and the warning is your defense against it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc. If your program works that's just because you're lucky in respect of the details of the calling convention on this implementation -- the same code might fail when compiled for Linux on some other CPU.

Answer (score 6):

Others have already discussed the differences between <malloc.h> and <stdlib.h>

As for the warning when neither is included, that is the definition of how C functions work.  A function without a prototype (which is what you have when you don't declare your own and don't include a header with one) is treated as a function with an `int` return type and an *unspecified* argument list.

The compiler will perform default promotions (e.g. float to double and others) and the function is called.  If the number of arguments used by the function is different from the number passed, or if the argument types after default promotions are not compatible with the function's implementation, it is undefined behavior.

See ISO 9899:1999 (C99) §6.5.2.2, ¶ 6:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the *default argument promotions*. If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the behavior is undefined. If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (, ...) or the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined.  If the function is defined with a type that does not include a prototype, and the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with those of the parameters after promotion, the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> - one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
> - both types are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of a character type or `void`.

In the case of calling `malloc()` without a prototype, this has the potential to be very bad.  `malloc()` accepts a `size_t` argument and returns a `void *` pointer.  If the result of default promotion of your integer argument produces an integer different in size from `size_t`, you will have undefined behavior.  And if `int` is a different size from `void *` (e.g. on 64-bit systems, where `int` is often 32-bits and `void *` will be 64-bits,) the returned pointer will be messed up.

Answer (score 5):

`<malloc.h>` is not a standard header and is thus not portable. The standard puts `malloc()` et al. in `<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score -1):

To learn the difference, you should read their contents for yourself.

By default, gcc reads neither.

When you read them, you will see that they declare `malloc` differently.