# code not printing linked list C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am writing C code to implement linked list.But while printing the contents of the list it prints the values taken for last node only.I have been debugging for long.Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct list {
    char *name;
    char *type;
    int occurance;
    struct list *prev;
    struct list *link;
};

struct list *start=NULL,*ptr,*newnode;

void main() {
    int choice = 0;
    char name1[10], type1[10];
    int occ;

    do {
        printf("Enter name:");
        scanf("%s", name1);
        printf("Enter type:");
        scanf("%s", type1);
        printf("Enter occurance:");
        scanf("%d", &occ);
        newnode = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        newnode->link = NULL;
        newnode->prev = NULL;
        newnode->name = name1;
        newnode->type = type1;
        newnode->occurance = occ;
        if(newnode == NULL) {
            printf("Memory could not be allocated!");
            // exit(0);
        }
        if(start == NULL) {
            start = newnode;
            ptr = start;
            printf("start is: %s", start->name);
        }
        else if(start->link == NULL) {
            start->link = newnode;
            newnode->prev = start;
            ptr = newnode;
        }
        else {
            ptr->link = newnode;
            newnode->prev = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->link;
        }
        printf("Enter 1 to continue: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    } while(choice == 1);

    // display
    ptr = start;
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", ptr->name);
        printf("%s ", ptr->type);
        printf("%d \n", ptr->occurance);
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }
}
```

I have tried making start and `newnode` local variables as well but it doesn't work.

Comment: Cqnqrd's answer has it. Another point, though: 1) your check for `newnode==NULL` is a little late, since you've already dereferenced `newnode` to set its members. And you don't need the "else if" for `start->link==NULL`; the same code in your `else{}` block will work for this case too.

Comment: Oh yes i noticed it now thanks @dvnrrs

Comment: change the signature of `main` to `int main(void)`. Also note that `malloc.h` is not standard. Use `stdlib.h` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cannot use equal operator to assign a `char *`. Instead you must use function `strcpy`.

Do not do this:

```
newnode->name=name1;
newnode->type=type1;
```

But do this:

```
strcpy(newnode->name, name1);
strcpy(newnode->type, type1);
```

Currently your whole `char*` are pointing to the same memory block.

**Edit:**
Since you are using pointers, you must allocate memory before copying value from one pointer to another (or you will encounter segfaults). So you also need to allocate your node's name and type memories with `malloc`:

```
//allocate memory of node's name attribute with the same amount as name1 (+1 for null terminating character)
newnode->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(name1)+1));
newnode->type= malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(type1)+1));
```

Comment: A little space (malloced or an array) would be useful too. :-)

Comment: He will have to `malloc()` some space for the strings before `strcpy()`ing them though.

Comment: True but I guess Op would find it himself. ;-)

Comment: Sorry for previous comment but strcpy causes program to crash due to segmentation fault

Comment: @user2538255 and did you read my and ooga's comments regarding you needing to *allocate space* before copying the string?

Comment: You mean to allocate memory to newnode->type? Because name1 is already an array

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to improve in your code so let's take it one by one. First, the behaviour you are seeing is because the structure members `name` and `type` of all nodes in your linked list point to the same memory location, i.e, to `name1` and `type1` respectively.

```
struct list {
    char *name;
    char *type;
    // other members
};
```

Here, `name` is a pointer to a character and so is `type`. In the `do while` loop in `main`, you read name and type of each node into the arrays `name1` and `type1` respectively in each iteration. Therefore, the previous values of `name1` and `type1` are overwritten and hence lost. Now you are assigning `name1` and `type1` to respective members of each newly created node.

```
// after allocating memory for a new node

newnode->name = name1;  // name1 evaluates to a pointer to name1[0]
newnode->type = type1;  // type1 evaluates to a pointer to type1[0]
```

Therefore `name` member of all nodes are pointing to `name1` which only retains the last string read, and similarly `type` member of all nodes point to `type1` which also has the last string read.

Now that we have discussed the behaviour of your program, what's the solution? You keep name and type of each node from getting overwritten by the next values entered. You do this by allocating memory for them every time you read them for a new node.

```
newnode->name = strdup(name1); // make a copy of name1 before it's overwritten
newnode->type = strdup(type1);  // make a copy of type1 before it's overwritten
```

`strdup` allocates enough memory to copy the string passed to it. It essentially does the same thing as `malloc` and `strcpy`. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252802/1809377).

Now let's come to other things starting from the top of your program.

- `malloc.h` is deprecated and not standard. Use `stdlib.h` instead. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973361/1809377).
- The C standard lays down two signatures for the `main` function: `int main(void);` and the other is `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);` More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2108208/1809377).
- While reading strings using `scanf`, you should guard against buffer overrun. If the user enters name and type which are longer than 9 characters, it will lead to undefined behaviour and even crash. You should replace `scanf("%s", name1)` with `scanf("%9s", name1)`. The `9` in the format string means that `scanf` will read at most 9 non-whitespace characters. One character space is left for the terminating null byte which it adds automatically.
- Check the return value of `malloc` for `NULL` immediately after the call. You program as such will simply crash if `malloc` fails to allocate memory.
- You don't need the `else if` block in your `do while loop`. It will never be entered except in the first iteration of the loop when it makes `start->previous = start` which is not what you want. `start->previous` should always be `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such an elaborated and detailed answer...specially for the improvements mentioned in the last :)