# linked list creation - program stops working after taking the inputs

Tags: c, linked-list

In the following linked list creation program, after input, the program stops working. The code after `printf("\n nodes entered are:\n)` is not running.

The if in for loop is used for creation of head or start node.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
    //creating a linked list
    typedef struct node
    {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
    }node;

int main()
{

    int i,n;
    node* temp;
    node* start=0;

    printf("Enter the no of elements in the linked list\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)                                                                //for first node
        {
        node* start=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        scanf("%d",&(start->data));
        start->link=NULL;
        temp=start;
        }
        else
        {
            node *nextnode=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
            scanf("%d",&(nextnode->data));
            temp->link=nextnode;
            nextnode->link=NULL;
            temp=nextnode;                                                      //updating temp for next iteration
        }
    }
    printf("\n nodes entered are:\n");
    temp=start;
    while(temp->link!=NULL)
    {
            printf("%d ",temp->data);
            temp=temp->link;
    }

printf("%d",temp->data);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with symbol (option `-g` for gcc) and run the code using a debugger (gbd), stepping through it line by line and you will become enlightend.

Comment: [`#include <stdlib.h>` instead of `malloc.h`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973311/difference-between-stdlib-h-and-malloc-h) and please [stop casting `malloc` in C programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: you would make it easier for yourself by having a pointer to the last node, then when you add just modify what last is pointing to. also create a function that reads an int instead of sprinkle your code with scanf's. e.g. `int readInt() { char line[128]; fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin); return atoi(line); }`

Comment: From the inclusion of `conio.h` I deduce Turbo-C and didn't this ancient compiler defined `char * malloc(...)`? @WhozCraig

Comment: @WhozCraig: A wait, thj OP most probably uses Turbo-C++?

Comment: @alk probably. It continues to confound me how many people on this planet use that steaming pile of a toolchain, especially when gcc and clang are utterly free and *infinitely* higher quality.

Comment: @Codeluv the technique you're trying to do is called *forward-chaining*, and it is considerably easier once you grasp how both single *and* two-level indirection work with pointers in C. [**see example here**](http://pastebin.com/fjyK9EFi).

Comment: @WhozCraig...I use dev C++...:)

Comment: So why you tag your question C then?

Comment: @WhozCraig can you enlight me more on what is forward chaining....if you can provide a link it would be a great help...!!

Comment: Did you bother to click the "see example here" link in the comment you read from me?

Comment: @WhozCraig haha...yeah i saw that...but iam newbie so i was asking if i could get some details on stuff written on that beautiful piece of code....!!

Comment: I suspect they do not teach "How to research" at school anymore, as gxxgling is already learned in the kindergarden?

Comment: @Codeluv I would be hard pressed to provide more info than that sample. It employs a pointer-to-pointer that always holds the address of the *next* pointer to populate with a new node once valid input is received. That particular sample works with any input, including a zero-length list, and breaks the for-loop on completion or invalid input detection. Its worth reading carefully, stepping through with a sheet of paper, pencil, and drawing a lot of boxes and arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this code snippet

```
    if(i==0)                                                                //for first node
    {
    node* start=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

to

```
    if(i==0)                                                                //for first node
    {
         start=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Otherwise inside the compound statement of the if statement you are declaring local variable start that hides previously declared variable start and  that will be deleted after execution of this compound statement.