# In C I am getting segmentation fault, i do not know why

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am making a Binary Search Tree that stores Multiple things in one instance, I have two errors That I ran into. The first one that happens in the function `insert` use to work in than randomly it stopped, the second one is in `print_tree_inorder` and I have no idea why that would be broken.

> 

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>


char* nameArray[50] = {};
char* number[50] = {};
char* ID[50] = {};
char* hours[50] = {};
char* pPH[50] = {};
int flag;
typedef struct node
{

    char* name;
    char* phoneNum;
    char* ID;
    char* hours;
    char* pPH;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
} node_t;




void insert(node_t * tree, char* name, char* phoneNum, char* hours, char* pPH);
void print_tree_inorder(node_t * current);

int main()
{
    char* n,p,id,h,pph;
    int numberOfTimes = 0;

    node_t * test_list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    /* set values explicitly, alternative would be calloc() */
    test_list->name =  "";
    test_list->phoneNum = "";
    //test_list->ID = "";
    test_list->hours = "";
    test_list->pPH = "";


    test_list->left = NULL;
    test_list->right = NULL;
    printf("Please enter in the amount of people you want: ");
    scanf("%d",&numberOfTimes);
    printf("\n");

         for(int i = 0; i<numberOfTimes; i++){
             printf("Please enter in name: ");
             scanf("%s", &n);
             nameArray[i] = n; 

             printf("Please enter in PhoneNumber: ");
             scanf("%s", &p);
             number[i] = p;
             printf("Please enter in Hours: ");
             scanf("%s", &h);
             hours[i] = h;
             //printf("\n");
             printf("Please enter in pay per hour: ");
             scanf("%s", &pph);
             pPH[i] = pph;


            insert(test_list,nameArray[i],number[i],hours[i], pPH[i] );

        }

    printf("\n In order\n");
    print_tree_inorder(test_list);
}

void insert(node_t * tree, char* name, char* phoneNum,  char* hours, char* pPH)
{  
    //unsigned int number = (unsigned int)ptr

    if (tree->name == 0)
    {
        /* insert on current (empty) position */
        tree->name = name;
        tree->phoneNum = phoneNum;
        //tree->ID = ID;
        tree->hours = hours;
        tree->pPH = pPH;
    }
    else
    {

        if ( strcmp(tree->name, name) > 0)
        {
            /* insert left */
            if (tree->left != NULL)
            {
                insert(tree->left, name, phoneNum, hours, pPH);
            }
            else /* no left nodes*/
            {
                tree->left = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
                /* set values explicitly, alternative would be calloc() */
                tree->left->name = name;
                tree->left->phoneNum = phoneNum;

                tree->left->hours = hours;
                tree->left->pPH = pPH;
                tree->left->left = NULL;
                tree->left->right = NULL;
            }
        }
        else /*add node to right */
        {
            if ( strcmp(tree->name, name) <= 0)
            {
                /* insert right */
                if (tree->right != NULL)
                {
                    insert(tree->right, name, phoneNum,  hours, pPH);
                }
                else
                {
                    tree->right = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
                    /* set values explicitly, alternative would be calloc() */
                    tree->right->name = name;
                    tree->right->phoneNum = phoneNum;

                    tree->right->hours = hours;
                    tree->right->pPH = pPH;
                    tree->right->left = NULL;
                    tree->right->right = NULL;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

void print_tree_inorder(node_t * current) {
    if (current == NULL) return;
    print_tree_inorder(current->left);
    printf(" %s %s %s %s\n", current->name, current->phoneNum,current->hours, current->pPH);

    print_tree_inorder(current->right);
}
```

Comment: Review `char* n; ....  scanf("%s", &n);`.  Where is the name being saved?

Comment: @chux Does it not get saved in nameArray[i] on the next line?

Comment: That is later code.  Where is the name being saved by the call `scanf("%s", &n)`? `n` is a pointer to nowhere.  `scanf("%s", &n);` should have caused a warning.  What compile are you using?

Comment: @chux I get the warning `warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]` I am using GDB

Comment: @chux Am I misusing something in this code? I am new to C so I do not know the syntax really well

Comment: There is much to this code, much more than I'd expect someone new to C to start.  Review how to read a line of user input and save as a string and then later print it.  `char buf[80];  scanf("%79s", buf); printf("%s\n", buf);`

Comment: You can also remove the second strcmp in the insert method.

Comment: @GlenvillePecor - treat warnings as errors

Comment: @chux im new to the syntax of C not coding. I know the fundamental structure to a lot of data structures.

Comment: @eckes ty! I shall do that

Comment: @edHeal ok will do from now on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems in your code. First of all [you should not include `malloc.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973311/difference-between-stdlib-h-and-malloc-h). It is deprecated.

Looks like there is some confusion around the declaration of `n,p,id,h,pph` variables. This statement:

```
char* n,p,id,h,pph;
```

declares only `n` as of type `char *` and rest of the variables `p,id,h,pph` declared as of type `char`.

Lets talk about the warnings reported by the compiler (I am using `gcc` compiler and providing `-Wall` and `-Wextra` options during compilation):

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra prg.c 
prg.c:56:26: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **' [-Wformat]
             scanf("%s", &n);
                    ~~   ^~
prg.c:61:24: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'char'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
             number[i] = p;
                       ^ ~
                         &
prg.c:64:23: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'char'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
             hours[i] = h;
                      ^ ~
                        &
prg.c:68:21: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'char'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
             pPH[i] = pph;
                    ^ ~~~
                      &
prg.c:35:15: warning: unused variable 'id' [-Wunused-variable]
    char* n,p,id,h,pph;
              ^
5 warnings generated.
```

You should not ignore the compiler warning messages. They are there for some reason.

**Warning** `1`:
`n` is of type `char *` and therefore `&n` is of type `char **`. The `%s` format specifier in `scanf()` expects the argument as an array and the array must have room for at least `input_size+1` characters.

You should declare `n` as array of characters, something like this:

```
char n[50];
// and for input
scanf("%49s", n);
```

**Warning** `2`:

`p` is of type `char` and `number[i]` is of type `char *`. Hence the assignment is incompatible. Also the `&p` is of type `char *`, thats why the compiler is not reporting any warning on statement:

```
scanf("%s", &p);
```

But this is not correct because `p` is of type `char` and it does not have enough room for the string input. Read more about format specifiers of [**`scanf()`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

You can do:

```
char p[50];
// and for input
scanf("%49s", p);
number[i] = strdup(p);
```

If you do not use `strdup`, all the pointers of `number` array end up pointing to same location. Alternatively, you can declare `p` as `char *` and explicitly handle the memory allocation/deallocation operation. Make sure to `free` the memory returned by `strdup`, once you are done with it. Same explanation for **warning** `3` and `4`.

**Warning** `5`:
Remove the unused variables from your code.

There is a scope of improvement in your code. Try to figure out them by yourself.

Comment: TY this will really help me out!