# Cannot use malloc.h in xcode?

Tags: c, xcode, malloc

```
#if 0

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

#include <malloc.h>

#define ColSize 2

void inputData(double*, int*, int i, int CSize);

void printdata(double*, int*, int i, int CSize);

int main(void)
{
    double *RATE;
    int *MIN_BALANCE;
    int i, CSize;
   
    RATE = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*ColSize);
    MIN_BALANCE = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*ColSize);
    
    i = 0;
    CSize = ColSize;
    inputData(RATE, MIN_BALANCE, i, CSize);
    printdata(RATE, MIN_BALANCE, i, CSize);
    
    free(RATE);
    free(MIN_BALANCE);
    
    return 0;
}
void inputData(double *RATE, int *MIN_BALANCE, int i, int CSize)
{
    for (i = 0; i < CSize; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf", (RATE+i));
        
        scanf("%d", (MIN_BALANCE+i));
    }
    return;
}
void printdata(double *RATE, int *MIN_BALANCE, int i, int CSize)
{
    for (i = 0; i < CSize; i++)
    {
        printf("rate: %f\n", *(RATE + i));
        printf("balance: %d\n", *(MIN_BALANCE + i));
    }
    return;
}
#endif
```

I ran the above code but I got an error message which is 'malloc.h'file not found. I am using xcode of Mac. How do I fix the error?

Comment: Are you sure about `#if 0` ?

Comment: By reading the documentation for malloc. [Try it.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) malloc.h is not a standard header, don't use it.

Comment: [Use `stdlib.h` instead of `malloc.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12973311/1679849) and things should work ok

Comment: btw : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973311/difference-between-stdlib-h-and-malloc-h

Comment: There is no header called malloc.h, that's why. Whoever told you to use it was confused.

Comment: Thank you all guys! I fixed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc.h` is non-standard.  Use `stdlib.h` [per the C standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3).