# Is there a way to initialize all int array elements to zero except for loop

Tags: arrays, c

Is there a way to initialize all int array elements to zero except a for loop where we loop through to set values to zero. Here the size of array is decided by input of user.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int num_cases = 0;
  scanf("%d", & num_cases);
  int arr_counter[num_cases];
  for (int x = 0; x < num_cases; x++) {
    arr_counter[x] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: [`man 3 memset`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html)

Comment: Either `memset(arr_counter, 0, sizeof(arr_counter));` or just zero-initialize the array when you define it: `int arr_counter[num_cases] = {};` ..  You should really test the return value from `scanf` is equal to 1 before using `num_cases` this way (and maybe also check that `num_cases` is not something insanely big or negative) before you create the VLA.

Comment: Related: [How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201101/45249)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `calloc` function available in `stdlib.h`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int num_cases;
    scanf("%d", &num_cases);
    int* arr = (int*)calloc(num_cases,sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Who will `free()` the heap allocated resource
??

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that in multiple ways under C standard. For example:

1. `memset()` *[Stack and Heap]*
2. `calloc()` *[Heap Only]*
3. loops, e.g., `do-while`, `while` and `for` *[Stack and Heap]*
4. `{ }` *[Stack Only]*

##### 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[10];
    size_t len_arr = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
    
    memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len_arr; i++)
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

*Note: We can use `memset()` to set all values as **0** or **-1** for integral data types also. It will not work if we use it to set as other values. The reason is simple, `memset()` works byte by byte.*

##### 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *arr = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
    if(!arr)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "bad ptr");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    
    free(arr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

*Note: You need to keep track of `arr` maximum length.*

*Note: `malloc()` leaves garbage value in your pointer, whereas `calloc()` uses `memset()` to initialize them to `0`.*

*Note: You need to free the heap allocated resource.*

##### 3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[10];
    size_t len_arr = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len_arr; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len_arr; i++)
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

*Note: You can use any of your favorite loop.*

##### 4

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[10] = {};
    size_t len_arr = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len_arr; i++)
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To initialize each element of Array you have two approaches:

1. If you are going for static memory allocation, you can initialize it like this:

   int arr[10] = {};
2. If you are going for dynamic memory allocation, you can use calloc function.

   int **arr = (int*) calloc(numberOfElementsInArray,sizeOfEachElement);

In your case, it would be like:

```
int *arr_counter = (int*) calloc(num_cases,sizeof(int));
```

NOTE: You need to include malloc.h header file to use calloc function.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to add that the correct header for calloc is <stdlib.h>. Also the pointer returned by calloc is a void-pointer, i.e., it will automatically be cast to an int pointer without the need of (int*).

Comment: Hey, it also works with <malloc.h>. Is there any difference between both the headers? And thanks for the pointer information.

Comment: The question between the difference of <malloc.h> and <stdlib.h> boils down to this answer [Difference <malloc.h> - <stdlib.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973311/difference-between-stdlib-h-and-malloc-h), in short; <malloc.h> is deprecated and not part of the c89 standard. Best wishes!